# Netrw <cr> behavior, new split under modified vsplit

Tags: vim, netrw

I used to use Nerdtree but I am switching to Netrw. In my .vimrc I have:

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
autocmd VimEnter * Vex
autocmd VimEnter * set winfixwidth
```

The  Behavior currently is that when I press enter the file will open on the right split which is what I want. This works correctly as long as the buffer remains unmodified. If the buffer is modified, pressing enter in the netrw split brings up a prompt asking me if I want to save.

The behavior I want is that if I have a modified buffer open in the right vsplit, and I press enter on a different file in the netrw split, to open a split in the right vsplit like this:

```
----------------
|Netrw|Modified|
|     |        |
|     |--------|
|     |New     |
----------------
```

Is this possible with Netrw?

Comment: If you are up for a workflow change, you can skip the project drawer setup. Just use `:Sex` to split and explore. You may want to `set splitbellow`.